# Inequalities Regarding the Decomposition of a Composite Number That Divides the Factorial of a Prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $c$ be a composite number with prime decomposition $c={\prod
}_{i=1}^np_i^{t_i}$, and suppose that for some prime $p$ it is true that $c\mid p!$. I think it's true that for all $i\in \{1,2,...,n \}$, $p_i<p$, but a rigorous proof remains elusive to me. Is my conjecture true?

Answer (score 1):

Not true. If $p|c|p!$, then it is false.

However, if we change the strict inequality to non-strict, we can proceed by contradiction:

Suppose that some $p_i> p$. Then $p_i\not|\ p!$, since $p_i$ is prime and $>p$. But, then $c\not|\ p$, so we have a contradiction.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it in a non strict sense. Anyway, why do we have to point out that $p_i$ is prime in your proof? Is it because every prime is a positive number?

Comment: No. It's because composite numbers can divide the factorial of numbers smaller than themselves, i.e. $6|4!$.

Comment: Does that mean: $c \mid l!$ iff $c$ is composite or $c \geq l$? Seems like a non trivial result to me.

Comment: @Kurome Not necessarily, it just means that there are some cases in which that is true. It's not all cases. For instance, $4\not|3!$. I'm not sure if there's a nice result as to when it happens.

Comment: I still do not get why if $p_i$ and $p$ are both primes where $p_i>p$, then $p_i \nmid p$. Also, I think you meant $c \nmid p!$ in your last sentence.

Comment: Ok, I think we can prove this using Euclid's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma